# How can I tell if my vector matches the variable values in r?

Tags: r, vector, integer

I am new to r. I am having trouble understanding if my code is accurate. Essentially, I have assigned a dummy variable 'edu.degree.level' to an existing variable in the data frame. The original variable had x9 possible values which are now assigned either a 1 or 0. However, when I run dpput () I see there are x10 integers in the vector for the variable, when I am expecting 9 based upon 9 being the number of integers for the original variable.

Here's my output:

```
dput(head(df1,10))
structure(list(edu.degree.level = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), immig.view = structure(c(7, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 7, 1, 
3, 1), label = "J1 Do you think immigration is good or bad for 
Britain's economy?", labels = c(`Not stated` = -999, `Don`t know` = -1, `1 Bad for economy`
= 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3,`4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7 Good for economy` = 7), class = "haven_labelled")), row.names
= c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The labels of the variable show as:

```
Labels:
value              label
-999         Not stated
-1         Don`t know
 1  1 Bad for economy
 2                  2
 3                  3
 4                  4
 5                  5
 6                  6
 7 7 Good for economy
```

Comment: Your `dput` output is corrupted, I think the fix is turning `Don\`t` into `Don't` (backtick to a single quote).

Comment: I'm confused about something. When you `dput(head(df1,10))`, it gives you 10 rows, so each column is a vector of length 10 ... because you said `head(df1,10)`, not because there are 10 levels of a categorical variable.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for spotting this. I will now attempt to amend this. I'm guessing that I go and rename somehow

Comment: @r2evans It is me that is confused and you have shown me my inaccurate reading of the  vector length! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels values and their names are the labels and levels, respectively, of what R calls a `"factor"`.

```
a <- attr(df1$immig.view, "labels")
df1$immig.view.2 <- factor(df1$immig.view, labels = names(a), levels = unname(a))
```

The following function can automate this procedure. The column `immig.view` will be changed in place, no test column `immig.view.2`.

```
labels2factor <- function(x){
  a <- attr(x, "labels")
  x <- factor(x, labels = names(a), levels = a)
  x
}

df1$immig.view <- labels2factor(df1$immig.view)

df1
#   edu.degree.level         immig.view
#1                 1 7 Good for economy
#2                 0                  4
#3                 1                  5
#4                 1  1 Bad for economy
#5                 0 7 Good for economy
#6                 1                  5
#7                 1 7 Good for economy
#8                 1  1 Bad for economy
#9                 1                  3
#10                0  1 Bad for economy
```

Comment: thank you. I am unclear what is happening in the answer. Why has immigration.view2 been created? What is meant by no test column? Thanks again.

Comment: @HoneyBadger In the first example I create `immig.view.2` as test column in order to compare it with the original `immig.view` without overwriting it. This is not what is wanted, the column should be changed, right? So in the second example, with the function, that is what happens, it's no longer a test.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand.